# Execution of a php function in crontab

Tags: php, linux, cron

I want to execute a php function in crontab like it is possible in a URL:

```
yourdomain.com/yourphp.php?function=pwdTimeout
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
* * * * * /var/..../webpage/yourphp.php?function=pwdTimeout
```

How can I execute a php function with the help of crontab. Help is highly appreciated.

My php-File looks like:

```
<?php 
define ('database', $database); // the variables are defined and tested 
define ('host', $host); 
define ('db_username', $db_username); 
define ('db_password', $db_password); 
if(isset($_GET['function'])){ 
$view = new functions(); 
$view->$_GET['function]();
}else{ 
echo 'Function not found'
} 

class functions{ 
function getUsername(){....} 
function setPassword(){...} 
function pwdTimeout(){...} 
} 
?>
```

where should I make changes in my code? thanks:)

Comment: No, you can't use URLs. (Unless with curl/wget to fake a web request). A direct crontab invocation can only use paths. Which doesn't allow `?x=y` query strings. Because query strings aren't paths.

Comment: sorry for missunderstanding, I don't want to execute as an URL, I just want to execute one function of my php in crontab, is this possible? I can execute the whole php but I just want to execute one function of this file

Comment: Have a look to [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Comment: Separate it out, or pass the function parameter via `argv` then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call your script in the CRON tab with your function name as an argument:

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/webpage/yourphp.php pwdTimeout
```

And retrieve the value of your argument with [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php):

```
$functionName = $argv[1]; // outputs pwdTimeout ([0] is the filename)
```

Please note that you can also use a key for your argument (`$ php yourphp.php function=pwdTimeout`) but you would need to `explode()` it, like so:

```
$parameters = explode('=', $argv[1]); // outputs array('function' => 'pwdTimeout')
```

Finally, you can use [`getopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) with the following call:

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/webpage/yourphp.php -f pwdTimeout
```

And use it like so:

```
$parameters = getopt('f:'); // outputs array('f' => 'pwdTimeout')
```

Comment: Please edit your question so your code is properly formatted.

Comment: I am a beginner and I'm hoping that you understand if I ask you now the next stupid question haha; my php file looks like this: `<?php define ('database', $database); // the variables are defined and tested define ('host', $host); define ('db_username', $db_username); define ('db_password', $db_password); if(isset($_GET['function'])){ $view = new functions(); $view->$_GET['function]();} else{ echo 'Function not found'} class functions{ function getUsername(){....} function setPassword(){...} function pwdTimeout(){...} } ?>` where should I implement your code?thanks:)

Comment: @Dominik: And replace `$view->$_GET['function']();` with `$view->$argv[1]();`

Comment: @Dominik: Have you replaced as adviced?

Comment: @Dominik: What `var_dump($argv[1]);` outputs when your script is run by CLI?

Comment: I get pwdTimeout, my problem is that I need for the other two methods the $_GET statement because i am using them via a weblink for my java project... I need an other way to make this.. maybe a new class?

Comment: @Dominik: Well, this is an entirely different question. You should ask a new question and, in the meantime, accept the answer that helped you and that is working.

Answer (score 1):

Without the GET params:

```
***** /bin/php /var/..../webpage/yourphp.php
```

With the GET params, but needs a webserver running with /var/..../webpage/ as DocumentRoot

```
***** /bin/wget -O /dev/null -q http://127.0.0.1/yourphp.php?function=pwdTimeout
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the wrong idea, cron job is a scheduler which runs script at a given time. So you need to put code in a file and configure that path in cronjob.