# how to write command to run cron on hostinger

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, hosting, cron-task

on hostinger I need to set up cron, for that I want to call controller function - my cron function located in `public_html/admin/application/controllers/cron.php`, here `send_birthmail()` has code to execute for cron in php , so what will be my command to execute con on hostinger

only file inside `public_html` is getting call via cron

my `public_html/admin/application/controllers/cron.php` should get called for `send_birthmail()` function

Comment: You can not directly invoke a function this way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32498173/1427878 has an approach to make this dynamic, so that a function name can be passed as an argument. (Whether you need that much, would be the question though. A separate script that includes the relevant source files and then simply _calls_ your `send_birthmail` function/method itself, might make more sense.)